# How to reduce number of queries in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iterator

I have a cats table. A cat `has_many` impressions, and an impression has  `impression_count` and `impression_day` columns - the count is an aggregate of all the people who've viewed a cat on a given day.

What I want to do is to create chart a line chart showing the number of impressions of a cat over however many dates. The JS charting library I'm using takes two arrays: `chartValues`, and `chartLabels`.

My controller action to generate those arrays:

```
def show
  @cat = Cat.find(params[:id])

  @from = @cat.created_at  
  @to = Time.now

  dates = (@from.to_date..@to)
  @chartLabels = dates.to_a.map {|date| date.strftime("%b %e")}

  shown = @cat.impressions.ordered.between(@from,@to)
  @chartValues = create_stats_for dates, shown
end
```

The private `create_stats_for` method is used to shovel a 0 into the values array if no impressions were recorded on that date:

```
private

def create_stats_for dates, values
    stat_values = []

    dates.each do |date|
      valid_impression = values.find_by impression_day: date
      if valid_impression
        stat_values << valid_impression.impression_count
      else
        stat_values << 0
      end
    end

    stat_values
end
```

**The issue**

My problem is that this is really inefficient, as I can be iterating over  all the impressions for several years worth of dates, resulting in incredibly slow page loads. There are cases where the impression count can be in the hundreds.

I feel like there's a much more efficient way to achieve the same goals, but I haven't figured it out yet - perhaps loading impressions into memory **once**, and iterating over those?

Any help you could give on this would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** The `ordered` and `between` methods (on the Impression model) as requested in the comments:

```
  def self.ordered
    order('impression_day asc')
  end

  def self.between(from,to)
    where("impression_day between ? and ?", from.to_date, to.to_date)
  end
```

Comment: where are ordered and between defined? is this in a scope?

Comment: Yes, I can edit them in to the question, but I didn't think they were pertinent?

Comment: looks like the @cat.impressions.ordered.between(@from,@to) is okay. what is confusing is the find_by. the way I would do this is that I would just create and array of zeros and after that iterate over the already retrieved values and just set the ones that are not zeros.